# Parameterized LCA with brightway2

Tags: python, parameters, lifecycle, brightway

After several iterations, I was finally able to update the values of existing parameters in a project to do a scenario based LCA using this for loop:

```
scores = np.empty(0)
# Iterate through each column in the DataFrame 'input_params'
for col in input_params.columns:

# Iterate through the index and parameter names of 'input_params'
    for idx, param_name in enumerate(input_params.index):

# Get the parameter value at the current row and column
        param_value = input_params.loc[param_name, col]

# Find matching 'ProjectParameter' objects by name and update their amount with 'param_value'
        for pjparam in ProjectParameter.select():
            if pjparam.name == param_name:
                pjparam.amount = param_value
            pjparam.save()

# For each 'ActivityParameter' object, recalculate its exchanges based on its group
    for param in ActivityParameter.select():
        param.recalculate_exchanges(param.group)

# Get an impact score using a function 'get_impact()' and append it to the 'scores' array
    score = get_impact()
    scores = np.append(scores, score)
```

In my case, the parameters were all defined as project parameters. My question:

Is there a more efficient way to update the parameterized exchanges in the model because this line is very slow and it is the only relevant command I can find in the API:
param.recalculate_exchanges(param.group)

The command .recalculate_exchanges() is too slow to execute